# Differentiability of projection

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Where $\pi_i:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R$ is projection onto the $i$th coordinate, the differentiability of $\pi_i$ at $X$ is given by:

$$\pi_i(X+H)-\pi_i(X)=\textrm{grad}\ \pi_i(X)\cdot H+||H||g(H)$$

Where $g$ tends to $0$ as its argument does. We deduce:

$$g(H)=\frac{h_i}{||H||}(1-x_i)$$

Where $h_i$ and $x_i$ are the $i$th coordinates of $H$ and $X$ respectively.

But how can this tend to zero? What if $H$ is approaching along the $i$th axis? Then $||H||=|h_i|$ and the limit either doesn't exist or is equal to $1-x_i$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, $\pi_i$ is linear and $g(H)=0$ for all $H$. Your mistake is that $\text{grad} \,\pi_i(X) = e_i$, the $i$th standard basis vector.