# What kind of derivative is this?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In this [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435761/differentiability-of-projection) the equation of the derivative of the projection map $\pi_i : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is given by

$$\pi_i(X+H)-\pi_i(X)=\textrm{grad}\ \pi_i(X)\cdot H+||H||g(H)$$

> What definition of derivative is used here?

I thought it should be the Frechet derivative but it seems not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the ordinary derivative; the equation you quoted is Taylor's theorem with remainder, written in a slightly unusual way:

$$f(x+h) = f(x) + h^T\nabla f(x) + ||h||g(x+h)$$
and $\lim_{h\to 0} g(x+h) = 0$.

Comment: The big-O estimate $O(\|h\|^2)$ for the remainder isn't true in general; consider for instance $n = 1$ and $f(x) = x^{3/2}$. You might be thinking of the Taylor _series_ where the function is analytic, hence twice-differentiable. In general the remainder is $o(\|h\|)$, i.e. little-o of order $\|h\|$.

Comment: @epimorphic Yes, I was thinking of $f$ in $C^2$ with bounded derivatives. Fixed.